# reverse sorting based on the third numerical key

Tags: linux, bash, file, sorting, sh

I have a file which looks like the following:

```
$ cat tmp
Albany, N.Y.    22.2    46.6    71.1    49.3    38.60   136 64.4    57
Albuquerque, N.M.   35.7    55.6    78.5    57.3    9.47    60  11.0    64
Anchorage, Alaska   15.8    36.3    58.4    34.1    16.08   115 70.8    39 / 60
Asheville, N.C. 35.8    54.1    73.0    55.2    47.07   126 15.3    39
Atlanta, Ga.    42.7    61.6    80.0    62.8    50.20   115 2.1 69 / 65
Atlantic City, N.J. 32.1    50.6    75.3    55.1    40.59   113 16.2    60 / 54
Austin, Texas   50.2    68.3    84.2    70.6    33.65   85  0.9 62 / 58
Baltimore, Md.  32.3    53.2    76.5    55.4    41.94   115 21.5    53
Baton Rouge, La.    50.1    66.6    81.7    68.1    63.08   110 0.2 52 / 46
Billings, Mont. 24.0    46.1    72.0    48.1    14.77   96  56.9    69
Birmingham, Ala.    42.6    61.3    80.2    62.9    53.99   117 1.5 60
Bismarck, N.D.  10.2    43.3    70.4    45.2    16.84   96  44.3    64
Boise, Idaho    30.2    50.6    74.7    52.8    12.19   89  20.6    64
Boston, Mass.   29.3    48.3    73.9    54.1    42.53   127 42.8    52 / 66
Bridgeport, Conn.   29.9    48.9    74.0    54.7    44.15   119 26.2    55 / 49
```

Say, in the first line after N.Y. is the temp in January. I want to reverse sort based on the temperature in Jan. I have the following commands but it's not really working and I'm sure there's more straightforward solution to this. Can you please guide me through?

```
tr -s " " < tmp > outtemp |  sort -rnt" " -k3 outtemp
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to do what you want (linux version):

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]([[:digit:]])/\t\1/g' < tmp |  sort -rnt$'\t' -k2
```

For example:

```
$ sed -E 's/[[:space:]]([[:digit:]])/\t\1/g' < tmp |  sort -rnt$'\t' -k2
Austin, Texas   50.2    68.3    84.2    70.6    33.65   85      0.9     62 /    58
Baton Rouge, La.        50.1    66.6    81.7    68.1    63.08   110     0.2     52 /    46
Atlanta, Ga.    42.7    61.6    80.0    62.8    50.20   115     2.1     69 /    65
Birmingham, Ala.        42.6    61.3    80.2    62.9    53.99   117     1.5     60
Asheville, N.C. 35.8    54.1    73.0    55.2    47.07   126     15.3    39
Albuquerque, N.M.       35.7    55.6    78.5    57.3    9.47    60      11.0    64
Baltimore, Md.  32.3    53.2    76.5    55.4    41.94   115     21.5    53
Atlantic City, N.J.     32.1    50.6    75.3    55.1    40.59   113     16.2    60 /    54
Boise, Idaho    30.2    50.6    74.7    52.8    12.19   89      20.6    64
Bridgeport, Conn.       29.9    48.9    74.0    54.7    44.15   119     26.2    55 /    49
Boston, Mass.   29.3    48.3    73.9    54.1    42.53   127     42.8    52 /    66
Billings, Mont. 24.0    46.1    72.0    48.1    14.77   96      56.9    69
Albany, N.Y.    22.2    46.6    71.1    49.3    38.60   136     64.4    57
Anchorage, Alaska       15.8    36.3    58.4    34.1    16.08   115     70.8    39 /    60
Bismarck, N.D.  10.2    43.3    70.4    45.2    16.84   96      44.3    64
```

#### OSX

The `sed` on OSX treats special characters differently.  On OSX, try:

```
sed -E $'s/[[:space:]]([[:digit:]])/\t\\1/g' < tmp |  sort -rnt$'\t' -k2
```

#### Notes

Pipes allow you to directly connect the output of one program with the input of another. Consequently, `outtemp` is not needed below:

```
tr -s " " < tmp > outtemp |  sort -rnt" " -k3 outtemp
```

The above could be replaced with:

```
tr -s " " < tmp |  sort -rnt" " -k3
```

There is, however, still the issue of making sure that the January temperature is in a consistent field.  This is complicated by the fact that some cities have names that are one word and others have names of two words.  `tr -s` does not help here as all it does is squeeze out repeats.

The approach here is to replace all spaces that precede a number with a tab.  This is done with `sed`.  (I assume that the city names are space-separated.)  With this change, the January temperature should be consistently in field 2.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I would assume that converting spaces to tabs is better than remove spaces as in my answer.

Comment: @MonaJalal Yes, and the reasons why it didn't work are explained in my answer.  Please try the code shown at the top of the answer. (I just edited the answer to try to show the code more clearly).

Comment: IDK why the author says this works for this challenge `sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 -nr` because it doesn't work when I test it on my machine `$ sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 -nr tmp`  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-sort-5

Comment: also when i run `sed -E 's/[[:space:]]([[:digit:]])/\t\1/g' < tmp |  sort -rnt$'\t' -k2` it adds t in the beginning of each entry

Comment: @MonaJalal What OS are you using?

Comment: @MonaJalal `sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 -nr` would work if the file had tabs before each temperature.  The author's version of the input must have had tabs.  The input displayed on the web does not.  Hence, the problem.  This is common with the web: characters like tabs are not preserved.

Comment: @MonaJalal I suspected that.  I asked because this question is tagged `linux`.  The `sed` command that I wrote was tested on linux.  The "it adds `t`" problem that you mentioned is consistent, though, with BSD (OSX) behavior.  I will add a version that I suspect will work better on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

`sort -k3nr input_file` this will however not work for Atlantic City, N.J. and Baton Rouge, La. where the third field is `N.J.` and `La.` You can remove that space with sed and then sort:

```
sed 's/\([^,]\) /\1/' input | sort -k3nr
```

This will however mangle the output since Atlantic City will become AtlanticCity and Baton Rouge will become BatonRouge.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to temporarily insert a "sentinel" character before the first number, then use that as the sort field delimiter, e.g.,

```
Austin, Texas   @50.2...
                ^
Baton Rouge, La.        @50.1...
                        ^
```

here's how:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/@&/' tmp | sort -nrk2 -t@ | tr -d @
```

(tested, working with OSX's sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93)

this approach has the advantage of being versatile, and also memorable because of its weirdness.

ref:

[use a temporary sentinel character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41656/65267)

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -nt$'\t' -k2
```

Above solution works fine. Explaination of the arguments

1. -n is for numeric sorting of the values(which is column 2)
2. t is for delimeter which is tab. the reason we use $'\t' is to ensure the tabs are considered properly. In case there are 2 consecutive tabs only using '\t' will consider it as 1. $ stands for delimeter starting.
3. -k is for which column to use for sorting. k stands for key(Column no. to specify it takes value as -ka,b where sorting is from a to b comlumns)

Refer the following link for more information.
[Unix Sorting Examples](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/08/linux-sort-command-examples.html)